# AJAX to get URL from inside PHP document

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, proxy

I am very new to web app creation so please be patient if I am not getting the technical terms right. This is code I found to use a web proxy, but it does not seem to work. I believe I have narrowed it down to it not pulling the path name correctly from my PHP file.

In my HTML file I am using java's xmlDoc.open command to open a PHP file and grab a local url. I need the xmlDoc.open to return the URL of http://192.168.1.100/state.xml. I believe there's something wrong with the way this line is formatted.

```
xmlDoc.open("GET", proxyName+"?path=state.xml&time="+timestamp, false);
```

Full code is below for the HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // name of the proxy script
    var proxyName = "proxy.php";
    // specify the automatic refresh rate here (in seconds)
    var refreshTimeSec = 3;
    
    var xmlDoc = false;
    var timeOutID = 0;
    
    // create the xml document resource
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
         xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
         xmlDoc = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    
    // this function requests the file state.xml from the device
    function getState() {
         
         var date = new Date();
         var timestamp = date.getTime();
         
         xmlDoc.open("GET", proxyName+"?path=state.xml&time="+timestamp, false);
         xmlDoc.send(null);
         if(xmlDoc.readyState == 4) {
              UpdateValues();
         }
                      
         timeOutID = setTimeout('getState()', refreshTimeSec*1000);
    }
</script>
```

The proxy php file looks like this:

```
<?php

// hostname
define('HOSTNAME', 'http://192.168.1.100/');
// get the request
$path = $_GET['path'];

// create the whole request hostname + path
$url = HOSTNAME.$path;

// get the Curl session
$session = curl_init($url);

// set some options for curl
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // don't return the header
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the result as a string
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3); // timeout if we don't connect after 3 seconds to the device

// send the request
$xml = curl_exec($session);

// return the result
echo $xml;

// close the curl connection
curl_close($session);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `xmlDoc.open(...)` correctly, but the reason your code does not work is that you don't call the `getState` function from outside of it, so it will never be called.

In addition, there are some other issues which I would like to point out:

- You are using synchronous XHR, which should be avoided because it blocks the browser's UI thread, making it unresponsive. In fact, many modern browsers have deprecated synchronous XHR (outside of Web workers) and may remove support for it in the future.
- You only need to use `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` if you want your app to work on Internet Explorer 6. If you *really* want to support this retired and almost never used browser, it is better to check for the existence of the `XMLHttpRequest` constructor rather than using `navigator.appName`.
- You should never pass a string to `setTimeout`, as this uses `eval()` internally (and if you do not know, [`eval` is very dangerous and should never be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)). Pass a function directly (that is, use `setTimeout(getState, time)` instead of `setTimeout('getState()', time)`).

If you address these issues then your JavaScript should be something like this:

```js
// name of the proxy script
var proxyName = "proxy.php";
// specify the automatic refresh rate here (in seconds)
var refreshTimeSec = 3;

var xmlDoc = false;
var timeOutID = 0;

// create the xml document resource
if (typeof(XMLHttpRequest) === 'undefined') {
    // If you want to support IE 6 ...
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else {
    xmlDoc = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

// this function requests the file state.xml from the device
function getState() {
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();

    xmlDoc.open("GET", proxyName + "?path=state.xml&time=" + timestamp);
    
    xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlDoc.readyState == 4 && ((xmlDoc.status === 0 || xmlDoc.status === 200))) {
            UpdateValues();
            timeOutID = setTimeout(getState, refreshTimeSec * 1000);
        }
        else {
            // Handle errors...
        }
    }
    
    xmlDoc.send();
}

getState();
```

If you are only targeting modern browsers, you can achieve this using the Fetch API and async generators:

```
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function* generateStates() {
    const proxyName = "proxy.php";
    const refreshTimeSec = 3;

    while (true) {
        const timestamp = Date.now();
        const response = await fetch(proxyName + "?path=state.xml&time=" + timestamp);
        yield await response.text();
        await delay(refreshTimeSec * 1000);
    }
}

async function main() {
    for await (let state of generateStates())
        UpdateValues(state);
}

main();
```